# Could anyone explain how to simplify $2\sin(45^\circ-x)\cos(45^\circ-x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

$$2\sin(45^\circ-x)\cos(45^\circ-x)$$

I know you have to use the double angle formula for sine, but what next?

Comment: Yeah, I got up to that, but the answer states cos 2x.

How do you expand sin 2(45-x)?

Answer (score 3):

Using the double angle formula for sine,
$$2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)=\sin(2\theta),$$
we see that
$$2\sin(45-x)\cos(45-x)=\sin(2\cdot(45-x))=\sin(90-2x)$$
Now use the identity that allows you to simplify $\sin(90-\theta)$, where in our case we have $\theta=2x$. You'll then want to use the double angle formula for cosine.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared things up!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

Hint : use
$$2 \sin a \cdot  \cos a = \sin 2a$$
and $$\sin(90-a)=\cos a$$

Answer (score 1):

double angle formula for sine,

> $2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)=sin(2\theta)$,

now,

> $2sin(45−x)cos(45−x)=sin(2⋅(45−x))=sin(90−2x)$.
>
> $sin(90-2x)=cos2x$

since,$(90-\theta)=cos(\theta)$, since cosine is positive in first and fourth quadrant, and maximum value of $\theta$ can not exceed $180^o$.

Now, Its easy ahead